# Does adjusting the volume in iTunes alter audio quality?

Tags: itunes, iphone

Will setting the volume adjustment to 100% change the quality of the song?

Furthermore, if I change the volume adjustment back to 0%, will any quality be lost?

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Keep in mind, if your speakers/headphones/amplifier aren't very good they will not be able to play loud audio accurately.

Comment: What do you mean by change the quality of the song? Because under certain circumstances it does change the quality of sound output.

Comment: @iskra if I change the volume adjustment to 100%, come back another day and changed it back to 0%, is the quality affected? In other words is the process reversible?

Comment: This is absolutely reversible since it doesn't do anything to an actual file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the volume to 100% will not affect the quality of the audio playback.

Comment: and when i set it back to 0% there's no data loss whatsoever right?

Comment: No data loss whatsoever. I just tried it, to be 100% certain.

Comment: Just to add to Mahnax's answer, iTunes does not re-encode the audio file when you set volume or even adjust start and end times. These changes are written to the audio file's metadata and in no way affect the actual file (other than telling iTunes or the iOS music player what to do when it comes time to play the song).